# Good tool/software package for simple web design

Tags: html

I am a server-side java developer without experience (nor much interest to be honest) in web design (basics on html and css only). However, I need to build a website as part of my work.

Ideally, I would like a tool with similar functionalities as http://www.jimdo.com, but with the possibility of geting the generated html files and deploy them anywhere.

I have tried Kompozer and Dreamweaver but I would like something simpler.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try BlueGriffon ( http://bluegriffon.org/ ) which is open source and works ok.

But in my opinion it's not going to be simpler than just using the basic skills you have and putting together a plain layout based on html tables.